# Build dynamic (conditional) WHERE SQL query in Golang

Tags: go, orm, printf

I'm using golang, go_reform, PostgreSQL. What i want to do is a REST search utility, and all went fine until I faced with conditional search query. "Conditional" here means I have 10 columns in a table to search in, and there may be ton of combinations so I can't handle them all separately. What i need is a query builder, but I have no understanding how can I implement this in Go. For now I have an idea like this, but it seems not really efficient

```
type Query struct {
    Id               *int64
    FirstName        *string
    MiddleName       *string
    LastName         *string
    AreaId           *int64
    Birthday         *time.Time
}

func (table *Query) Find() (*User) {
    if table.Id != nil {
        idstr := fmt.Sprintf("WHERE Id = %d AND ", table.Id)
    }
    else idstr := "WHERE "
    }
    if table.FirstName != "" {
        firststr := fmt.Sprintf("FirstName = %s AND", table.FirstName)
    }
    else firststr := ""
}//and so on
```

That feels really awkward so I'm wondering is there any better way to determine the fields that came to the `Find()` and build a SQL query based on this. (Actually it's coming in JSON and binding to `Query` struct, so maybe there is a way without struct). There also may be SQL workarounds, but I think it would be more efficient to build query without all possible columns.

**EDIT:** By the way, making my Google search query more accurate, i found a bunch of things related to my problem, probably i will try to use it now. For those who interested too:
[old go playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/QN0S_O4dqe)

[Making dynamic SQL queries to a MySQL DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46859705/making-dynamic-queries-in-golang-and-mysql)

[gorp package](https://github.com/go-gorp/gorp) (snippets thing sounds very promising)

Comment: Aside from the compilation errors (i.e. elector.FirstName is a pointer, so cannot be compared to a string), it's a reasonable approach.

Comment: It's just an example, i already have all the code written but I really don't like the way it works :/

Comment: What problem do you have with it?

Comment: Well, this formatting of AND often leads to errors, and also I can't use my ORM as I don't know exact amount of placeholders (i may do it in a same if-else strings are building, but it's going to be monstrous piece of code), I wish there is more high-level way of doing this.

Comment: Not using an ORM is a good thing :)

Comment: But on a more serious note, what good is an ORM if it doesn't do this for you?

Comment: don't use pointers for string and int64 types. go is value-oriented language, indirectly you are putting pressure on GC. What you are asking is rather too complicated, there is sql parser written for [vitess](https://github.com/vitessio/vitess) in go, maybe you can get some ideas or help from there.

Comment: Do not use `fmt` verbs (the `%d, %s` etc. in your strings) to construct your queries, you are setting yourself up for some sql injection.

Comment: Got the idea about the pointers, but I can't handle nil then. What do you think about doing it json-way and not doing the struct for it? Don't have an idea how this should work, maybe you have a hint on this?

Comment: Okay, i will use sql.Prepare for string building

Comment: sql.Prepare doesn't do string building.

Comment: So, basically nobody said that building query can be done another way, which is really sad. This code is such a boilerplate, i think there is a library for that for sure.

Comment: All pro's and con's aside, I would seriously consider using an ORM like gorm for something like this. Dynamically creating the WHERE clause is something we all do from time to time, but if you need to support searching using 10 columns, I don't think indexing and performance are the #1 priority, and in that case I'd opt for the easy solution over the more performance-oriented one any day

Comment: I'm absolutely agree with you, but i need database-first solution, so I'm limited to xorm (don't like), reform (using now), and sqlboiler (used, nah, not fits my current project), and, AFAIK reform can't do such thing. There is SelectOneTo\From with a "tail" parameter, which is actually a prepared statement snippet, but i have no idea how would i use it without the code i provided above, i need to build this string anyway.

Comment: @Flimzy Are you saying that is an ORM is not good if you need efficient solutions. So it is better to use dynamic queries rather that using ORM.

Comment: My opinion about ORMs is that they make already easy tasks slightly easier, and complex tasks impossible. I think they are evil, and should always be avoided, no exceptions.  My opinion isn't always popular, but that's my opinion.

Comment: @PavelNasevich If you don't mind using reflect you can do something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/BlADhht9PwO

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: An ORM, per se, is not what's needed. A query builder is. ORMs often include these as a feature, but there's no reason you need an ORM to get that feature.

Comment: @mkopriva I want to thank you, your variant is good (final is without reflection tho, but your was a huge hint in terms of DB placeholders)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, I found the solution. Big thanks to [Cerise Limón](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46859776/10360512), whose code fits perfectly for me.

**The solution I ended up with**

Controller

```
func Find(c echo.Context) (err error) {
model := &models.Query{}
if err = c.Bind(model); err != nil {
    return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, u.Message(false, "Bad request"))
}
resp := model.Find()
return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, resp)
```

Model

```
type Query map[string]interface{}

func (model Query) Find() (Query) {
    var values []interface{}
    var where []string
    for k, v := range model {
        values = append(values, v)
        //MySQL Way: where = append(where, fmt.Sprintf("%s = ?", k))
        where = append(where, fmt.Sprintf(`"%s" = %s`,k, "$" + strconv.Itoa(len(values))))
    }
    string := ("SELECT name FROM users WHERE " + strings.Join(where, " AND "))
    //for testing purposes i didn't ran actual query, just print it in the console and returned JSON back
    fmt.Println(string)
    return model

}
```

Update: for PostgreSQL users (thanks to @mkopriva and his [playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/BlADhht9PwO)), I'm able to have this placeholder thing working right on PostgreSQL

Comment: Basically, i still have a one little problem - i use PostgreSQL, so placeholder "?" is a no-go here, and i don't have an idea how to make it replace it to $1, $2 and so on.

Comment: This can leave you open to SQL injection no? Where are you sanitizing your values?

Comment: This is not susceptible to SQL injection because placeholders are used for parts of the query outside the application's direct control.

Answer (score 2):

In orm `GORM`,we do it like

```golang
if con1 {
    db.Where("con1 =?", con1Flag)
}
```

If the orm you write yoursefl, I suggest change into gorm.Or you can refer to the orm you're using ,whether it has the same ussage like code above.
If you're coding yourself, do it whatever you like.
If you'r working in group, I guess using a mature orm is much better

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL

Query(string sql, args...)

Here when I am passing values to Query in the form 
Query(string,values) 
It is throwing an error that only one value is added, expected should be 2, How should the interface array be passed as args to Query

I found the answer: you need to pass it in as Query(string, values...)