# How to implement repository in Go in case of complex requests?

Tags: go, repository-pattern

Suppose we have multiple products with next fields: id, name, type, price, weight.
I want to return products that match some complex filter, for example:

- name like '%bla%' and type = 3 - return all products that contains specific substring in name and belongs to specific type
- name like '%bla%' and type=4 and weight/price < 10
- (name like '%bla%' and type=5) or (name like '%lala%' and type=6 and price < 200)

I don't want to implement separate method for every possible filter.

Repository fetches data from db (I use postgres).

Comment: I don't use the repository pattern so this may not be the best suggestion but, you could do something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/7ddTvx8xFXk

Comment: `I don't want to implement separate method for every possible filter.` consider you will scatter your model into the application. Often leading to strings artifacts that are unmanaged by the compiler, adding burdens to the maintenance.

Comment: @mkopriva I have come almost to the same solution but in my case filter is a tree not an array)) https://play.golang.org/p/qiLb6tzy_LI

Comment: what is yor db engine ? You have not tell. It might matter.

Comment: @mh-cbon I use postgres.

Comment: the problem with that question is that you are going down a path that is way more complex than what it look likes at first sight. See the size of GORM query builder framework https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/tree/master/clause

Comment: look also this package that does sql parsing. https://github.com/kyleconroy/sqlc/tree/main/internal/sql It is not easy at all as son as you get serious.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52327710/build-dynamic-conditional-where-sql-query-in-golang

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

type Items struct{
    _id string;
    _name string;
    _type int;
    _price float64;
    _weight float64;
}

func (i *Items) filter(bla string) []Items{
    items := []Items{
        Items{
            _id: "i_78676758",
            _name: "packet1",
            _type: 4,
            _price: 44.65,
            _weight: 3.6,
        },
        Items{
            _id: "i_546458",
            _name: "packet2",
            _type: 5,
            _price: 234.65,
            _weight: 123.6,
        },
        Items{
            _id: "i_5879788",
            _name: "packet2",
            _type: 5,
            _price: 34.65,
            _weight: 13.6,
        },
        Items{
            _id: "i_7858758",
            _name: "packet3",
            _type: 3,
            _price: 284.65,
            _weight: 23.6,
        },
    };
    var validID = regexp.MustCompile(regexp.QuoteMeta(bla))
    new_items := []Items{}
    for _, item := range items{
        switch{
        case ((validID.MatchString(item._name)) && (item._type == 3)):
            new_items = items
            break;
        case ((validID.MatchString(item._name)) && (item._type == 4) && (item._price < 10) && (item._weight < 10)):
            new_items = append(new_items, item)
        case (((validID.MatchString(item._name)) && item._type == 5) || ((validID.MatchString(item._name)) && (item._type == 6) && (item._price < 200))):
            new_items = append(new_items, item)
        case ((validID.MatchString(item._name)) && (item._price > 100)):
            new_items = append(new_items, item)
        default:
        }
    }
    return new_items;
}

func main(){
    item := &Items{
        _id: "i_7858758",
        _name: "packet",
        _type: 4,
        _price: 234.65,
        _weight: 23.6,
    }
    items := item.filter("et2")
    fmt.Println(items)
}
```

In the above code **Items** struct holds the data which has **filter** method which loops over **items** which is a **[]Items** and filter on the basis of text which is matched by **Regexp** and **switch case** to validate other things and finally returns a **[]Items** which holds the filtered data.

Comment: There are several things that confuse me about this solution:
1. What if I have 100 possible filters? I have to implement 100 cases?
2. Repository have to fetch data from db. And fetch all products from db doesn't sound effective.

Comment: @aggravator You didn't mention what db you are using, please let us know and yes fetching all the data is out of question. Either you fetch the filtered data `using db query` or you get data in chunks and then process it.

Comment: I use postgres.

Comment: I don't know postgres. But on a quick internet search i found a go package for postgres `go-pg/pg` and a sql command which might be useful to you. `SELECT
 *,
 CASE
  WHEN (Price IS NOT NULL AND Price >= 10) AND (Name LIKE '%et%') THEN items.Id
 END AS newid
FROM items;` You can use it in the `filter function` to get expected results. That way you don't need switch case.